# How to solve Error: {E201} Multiple children of property element in RDF without losing the separation?

Tags: rdf, rdfs

I'm learning how to create RDF and here is mine for 3 types of coffee

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<rdf:RDF
xmlns:ex = "http://example.org/" 
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="ex:CoffeeShop">
        <ex:serves>
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="ex:Coffee">
              <ex:name>Brazilian Espresso</ex:name>
              <ex:usesTechnique>Espresso</ex:usesTechnique>
              <ex:isMadeOf>Brazilian Coffee Beans</ex:isMadeOf>
              <ex:roastingLevel>8</ex:roastingLevel>
            </rdf:Description>
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="ex:Coffee">
              <ex:name>Special Arabica</ex:name>
              <ex:usesTechnique>french pressed</ex:usesTechnique>
              <ex:isMadeOf>Arabica Beans</ex:isMadeOf>
              <ex:roastingLevel>6</ex:roastingLevel>
            </rdf:Description>
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="ex:Coffee">
              <ex:name>Colombian Latte</ex:name>
              <ex:served>non-steamed milk</ex:served>
              <ex:isMadeOf>Colombian Cocoa Beans</ex:isMadeOf>
              <ex:roastingLevel>9</ex:roastingLevel>
            </rdf:Description>
        </ex:serves>
    </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

but I got this error when I checked it against RDF W3C validator.

```
Error: {E201} Multiple children of property element[Line = 16, Column = 52]
Error: {E201} Multiple children of property element[Line = 22, Column = 52]
```

But if I removed the  I will lose the separation, how to solve these errors without losing the separation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a possibility, without pulling in an additional rdfs dependency

```xml
<rdf:RDF
xmlns:ex = "http://example.org/" 
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="CoffeeShop">
    <ex:coffee_type rdf:parseType="Collection">
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="ex:Coffee1">
              <ex:name>Brazilian Espresso</ex:name>
              <ex:usesTechnique>Espresso</ex:usesTechnique>
              <ex:isMadeOf>Brazilian Coffee Beans</ex:isMadeOf>
              <ex:roastingLevel>8</ex:roastingLevel>
            </rdf:Description>
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="ex:Coffee2">
              <ex:name>Special Arabica</ex:name>
              <ex:usesTechnique>french pressed</ex:usesTechnique>
              <ex:isMadeOf>Arabica Beans</ex:isMadeOf>
              <ex:roastingLevel>6</ex:roastingLevel>
            </rdf:Description>
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="ex:Coffee3">
              <ex:name>Colombian Latte</ex:name>
              <ex:served>non-steamed milk</ex:served>
              <ex:isMadeOf>Colombian Cocoa Beans</ex:isMadeOf>
              <ex:roastingLevel>9</ex:roastingLevel>
            </rdf:Description>
    </ex:coffee_type>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

I took the syntax hint from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_rdf.asp), search for `RDF Collections`